# Matrix of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Consider the linear map $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$,
$$X \to AX$$
where 
$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I'm asked to find "the corresponding matrix with respect to the basis $ \{E_{ij}\}."$

I am not exactly sure what is meant, but I know that 
$$X=ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3 + de_4.$$
$$AX = aAE_{11} + bAE_{12} + cAE_{21} + dAE_{22}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a-c & b-d \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}.$$

The answer is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
What is this matrix and how is it related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $E_{11}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and$$A.E_{11}=E_{11}=1\times E_{11}+0\times E_{12}+0\times E_{21}+0\times E_{22},$$the first column of the matrix is$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$Can you do the rest now?